# Use object's variables before creating it

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to create a "pointer" to a variable of an object before actually creating it like that:

```js
anotherFunc();

function anotherFunc()
{
  let obj3 = { param1 : obj1.hp , param2 : obj2.hp };

  myFunction(obj3);
}

function myFunction(parameters)
{
  let obj1 = {
    hp: 100
  };

  let obj2 = {
    hp: 50
  };

  console.log(parameters);
  thirdFunc(parameters);
}

function thirdFunc({param1, param2}={})
{
  console.log(param1);
}
```

If I run this code of course I get an error because obj1 and obj2 do not exist at that moment. But I want to have an ability to tell the program: "hey, for now those variables and objects do not exist, but when I tell you you need to look for them in your closure and get their values". Is it even possible to have such functionality in js?

// **EDIT**

Sorry, it seems like I indeed asked inappropriate question. It is not possible to do what I want.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: You cant access `obj1` and `obj2` outside of scope of `myFunction`

Comment: `look for them in your closure and get their values` but they aren't in the closure and would never even be in that example. It seems to me you have some misunderstanding when it comes to scopes which probably led you to the wrong path. Can you explain what you're actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

It does not work in the order, you have.

You could bind an object to a function and take [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) as reference for a result. [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) returns a new function which has to be called for a result.

```js
function getObject() {
   return { param1: this.obj1.hp, param2: this.obj2.hp };
}

function bindObject() {
    let obj1 = { hp: 100 };
    let obj2 = { hp: 50  };

    return getObject.bind({ obj1, obj2 });      
}

console.log(bindObject()());
```

Answer (score 0):

At runtime, your `obj1` is not declared yet when you call your `anotherFunc` and that you arrive to this line `let obj3 = { param1 : obj1.hp , param2 : obj2.hp };`. You can't access a variable which is not declare or you will get `variableName is not defined`. In your case each variable are available only in their scope (function).

I don't know what you are trying to achieve but maybe something like that :

```js
function anotherFunc() {
  let obj3 = { param1 : null , param2 : null };

  myFunction(obj3);
}

function myFunction(obj) {
  obj.param1 = 100;
  obj.param2 = 50;

  console.log(obj);
  thirdFunc(obj);
}

function thirdFunc({param1, param2} = {}) {
  console.log(param1);
}

anotherFunc();
```

If you need something else, could you describe more what do you want ?